# python regex lookbehind, lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I want to look/parse for a unit (Pa, K, degC, °C) and want to make sure it is followed and preceded by something other than a letter because K, Pa or whatever units I match are obviously part of many many words. ;-)

The regex ***[^A-Za-z][Dd][Ee][Gg][Cc][^A-Za-z]*** works, however it matches in text: *blablablatext degC blablabla*
the degC + whitespaces. I want to match only degC!

I tried ***(?![A-Za-z])
[Dd][Ee][Gg][Cc]
(?>![A-Za-z])*** but it doesn't match ever and I don't know how. If I use only the negative lookahead or the negative lookbehind it works and matches only degC without whitespaces.

Could someone please explain me how to make sure my target word is preceded and followed by anything other than letters?

Comment: the negative lookahead `(?!`..`)` must be at the end and the negative lookbehind `(?<!`..`)` at the start otherwise word boundaries may be used

Comment: It helps us test solutions if you show us a few lines of positive and negative examples of  expressions with temperatures.

Comment: thank you it works perfectly! ***(?<![A-Za-z])[Dd][Ee][Gg][Cc](?![A-Za-z])*** is used with the following header: T62_Manifold_Anode_inlet degC T63_Manifold_Cathode_outlet degC T64_Manifold_Anode_outlet degC T71_Stack_1_Cathode_inlet degC T71.1_Stack 1 Cathode Inlet Top T71.2_Stack 1 Cathode Inlet Middle T71.3_Stack 1 Cathode Inlet Bottom left T71.4_Stack 1 Cathode Inlet Bottom right T73_Stack_1_Cathode_outlet degC T73.1_Stack 1 Cathode Outlet Top  and matches exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0):

the negative lookahead `(?!`..`)` must be at the end and the negative lookbehind `(?<!`..`)` at the start, also the `/i` flag or `(?i:`..`)` can be used to simplify expression

```
(?<![a-z])(?:pa|k|degc|°C)(?![a-z])
```

Comment: thank you this works perfectly! however can i ensure that its not distinguished whether using upper- or lowercase letters with that method?

Comment: this is what i meant with the flag `/i`: for case insensitive, can be either global using option or limited to a part of the regex using `(?i:`..`)` construct if supported for example `(?i:(?<![a-z])(?:pa|k|degc|°C)(?![a-z]))`

Comment: you're welcome, please, don't forget to accept and upvote